# В каком виде можно передать прокси с логином и паролем? (proxy handler)

Tags: python, django, requests, proxy

Есть код, в который можно передать proxy в таком формате:

```
proxy = {'http': '207.164.21.34:3128'}
```

Проблема том, что у меня есть еще логин и пароль для доступа к этому прокси. Я так понимаю, что в таком случае мне нужно передавать прокси в аргумент proxy_handler, но в каком именно формате не понимаю.

Сам код:

```
def __init__(self, username, password, **kwargs):
    """

    :param username: Login username
    :param password: Login password
    :param kwargs: See below

    :Keyword Arguments:
        - **auto_patch**: Patch the api objects to match the public API. Default: False
        - **drop_incompat_key**: Remove api object keys that is not in the public API. Default: False
        - **timeout**: Timeout interval in seconds. Default: 15
        - **api_url**: Override the default api url base
        - **cookie**: Saved cookie string from a previous session
        - **settings**: A dict of settings from a previous session
        - **on_login**: Callback after successful login
        - **proxy**: Specify a proxy ex: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888' (ALPHA)
        - **proxy_handler**: Specify your own proxy handler
    :return:
    """
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.auto_patch = kwargs.pop('auto_patch', False)
    self.drop_incompat_keys = kwargs.pop('drop_incompat_keys', False)
    self.api_url = kwargs.pop('api_url', None) or self.API_URL
    self.timeout = kwargs.pop('timeout', 15)
    self.on_login = kwargs.pop('on_login', None)
    self.logger = logger

    user_settings = kwargs.pop('settings', None) or {}
    self.uuid = (
        kwargs.pop('guid', None) or kwargs.pop('uuid', None) or
        user_settings.get('uuid') or self.generate_uuid(False))
    self.device_id = (
        kwargs.pop('device_id', None) or user_settings.get('device_id') or
        self.generate_deviceid())
    # application session ID
    self.session_id = (
        kwargs.pop('session_id', None) or user_settings.get('session_id') or
        self.generate_uuid(False))
    self.signature_key = (
        kwargs.pop('signature_key', None) or user_settings.get('signature_key') or
        self.IG_SIG_KEY)
    self.key_version = (
        kwargs.pop('key_version', None) or user_settings.get('key_version') or
        self.SIG_KEY_VERSION)
    self.ig_capabilities = (
        kwargs.pop('ig_capabilities', None) or user_settings.get('ig_capabilities') or
        self.IG_CAPABILITIES)
    self.application_id = (
        kwargs.pop('application_id', None) or user_settings.get('application_id') or
        self.APPLICATION_ID)

    # to maintain backward compat for user_agent kwarg
    custom_ua = kwargs.pop('user_agent', '') or user_settings.get('user_agent')
    if custom_ua:
        self.user_agent = custom_ua
    else:
        self.app_version = (
            kwargs.pop('app_version', None) or user_settings.get('app_version') or
            Constants.APP_VERSION)
        self.android_release = (
            kwargs.pop('android_release', None) or user_settings.get('android_release') or
            Constants.ANDROID_RELEASE)
        self.android_version = int(
            kwargs.pop('android_version', None) or user_settings.get('android_version') or
            Constants.ANDROID_VERSION)
        self.phone_manufacturer = (
            kwargs.pop('phone_manufacturer', None) or user_settings.get('phone_manufacturer') or
            Constants.PHONE_MANUFACTURER)
        self.phone_device = (
            kwargs.pop('phone_device', None) or user_settings.get('phone_device') or
            Constants.PHONE_DEVICE)
        self.phone_model = (
            kwargs.pop('phone_model', None) or user_settings.get('phone_model') or
            Constants.PHONE_MODEL)
        self.phone_dpi = (
            kwargs.pop('phone_dpi', None) or user_settings.get('phone_dpi') or
            Constants.PHONE_DPI)
        self.phone_resolution = (
            kwargs.pop('phone_resolution', None) or user_settings.get('phone_resolution') or
            Constants.PHONE_RESOLUTION)
        self.phone_chipset = (
            kwargs.pop('phone_chipset', None) or user_settings.get('phone_chipset') or
            Constants.PHONE_CHIPSET)
        self.version_code = (
            kwargs.pop('version_code', None) or user_settings.get('version_code') or
            Constants.VERSION_CODE)

    cookie_string = kwargs.pop('cookie', None) or user_settings.get('cookie')
    cookie_jar = ClientCookieJar(cookie_string=cookie_string)
    if cookie_string and cookie_jar.auth_expires and int(time.time()) >= cookie_jar.auth_expires:
        raise ClientCookieExpiredError('Cookie expired at {0!s}'.format(cookie_jar.auth_expires))
    cookie_handler = compat_urllib_request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar)

    proxy_handler = kwargs.pop('proxy_handler', None)
    if not proxy_handler:
        proxy = kwargs.pop('proxy', None)
        if proxy:
            warnings.warn('Proxy support is alpha.', UserWarning)
            parsed_url = compat_urllib_parse_urlparse(proxy)
            if parsed_url.netloc and parsed_url.scheme:
                proxy_address = '{0!s}://{1!s}'.format(parsed_url.scheme, parsed_url.netloc)
                proxy_handler = compat_urllib_request.ProxyHandler({'https': proxy_address})
            else:
                raise ValueError('Invalid proxy argument: {0!s}'.format(proxy))
    handlers = []
    if proxy_handler:
        handlers.append(proxy_handler)

    # Allow user to override custom ssl context where possible
    custom_ssl_context = kwargs.pop('custom_ssl_context', None)
    try:
        https_handler = compat_urllib_request.HTTPSHandler(context=custom_ssl_context)
    except TypeError:
        # py version < 2.7.9
        https_handler = compat_urllib_request.HTTPSHandler()

    handlers.extend([
        compat_urllib_request.HTTPHandler(),
        https_handler,
        cookie_handler])
    opener = compat_urllib_request.build_opener(*handlers)
    opener.cookie_jar = cookie_jar
    self.opener = opener

    # ad_id must be initialised after cookie_jar/opener because
    # it relies on self.authenticated_user_name
    self.ad_id = (
        kwargs.pop('ad_id', None) or user_settings.get('ad_id') or
        self.generate_adid())

    if not cookie_string:   # [TODO] There's probably a better way than to depend on cookie_string
        if not self.username or not self.password:
            raise ClientLoginRequiredError('login_required', code=400)
        self.login()

    self.logger.debug('USERAGENT: {0!s}'.format(self.user_agent))
    super(Client, self).__init__()
```

Comment: Попробуй http:// user:passwd@host:port

Comment: формат подошел, только не под тот аргумент который я думал.
proxy = 'http://login:pass@host:port'
работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось можно просто в прокси передать следующее:

```
proxy = 'login:pass@host:port'
```